# How to change settings on module installation?

Tags: module, installation, settings, odoo, odoo-8

I want to change a value in the settings of `sale.config.settings`. I found [this way](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/how-to-change-settings-on-module-installation-72694) to do it. But I would like to use the api of Odoo v8. Is that possible? All the examples I found in the source code are using `osv.osv_memory`

Answer (score 0):

xml ===================

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
 <data>
       <function model="my.model.init" name="_init_settings" />

 </data>
</openerp>
```

python ======================

```
from openerp import api, models
class my_model_init(models.TransientModel):

    _name = ''my.model.init"
    @api.multi
    def _init_settings(self):
        sale_settings_pool = self.env['sale.config.settings']
        sale_settings_id = sale_settings_pool.create({'group_route_so_lines':True})
        sale_settings_obj = sale_settings_pool.browse(sale_settings_id)
        sale_settings_obj.execute()  # this call is actually changes the setting, you're missing this step.
        return True
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your code, but I get this error `ParseError: "old_api() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)" while parsing /my_module/data/test_init.xml:6, near
<function model="my.model" name="_set_settings"/>`. Maybe the tag `function` in xml is deprecated in the new api