# add defaults configuration in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8

I wanna set default configuration
Say in purchases I wanna ( Use 'Real Price' or 'Average' costing methods.)
checked by default and in sales configuration i want ( Generate invoices after and based on delivery orders) to be check Using custom modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it creating a new module using a `osv.osv_memory` model. Take a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162964/how-to-change-settings-on-module-installation/31199994) and the [solution](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/how-to-change-settings-on-module-installation-72694) (so far)